# how to add column to a mysql table by selecting columns from another table

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I know how to create table based on columns of other mysql table
as

```
create table table_name as select column1,column2 from table2;
```

Now i want to know how to add column to a table by selecting columns from another table,
something like below

```
alter table table1 add column as select column from table2
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a table's structure with the following query:

```
select * 
from information_schema.table_name
```

Which you can then use the result to either create or alter another table.